# Dell XPS 12, Windows 8.1 single language Chinese. How to change to English

Tags: windows-8, dell-xps, language-pack

I bought a Dell XPS 12 in China and made the mistake of not buying a pro version of Windows 8.1 on it. To change my language to English I have been searching for solutions but haven't managed so far. Help would be greatly appreciated.

My preferred solution is installing the English language pack (instead of a clean install). I have also downloaded a genuine product key for Windows 8.1 from the US but changing the key didn't seem to work (both via settings and via cmd admin).

I downloaded the language pack and tried to install ([How to install a new "display language" onto Windows 8.1 Single Language?](https://superuser.com/questions/666978/how-to-install-a-new-display-language-onto-windows-8-1-single-language))

The problem I run into after entering `dism /Online /Add-Package / PackagePath:C:\lp.cab` is

'An error occurred trying to open - C:\lp.cab Error: 0x8007003'

I tried changing the file name to lp.mlc but this only gave the same error. I have gone though all the other posts but couldn't find the solution.

Any help solving this problem is much appreciated, its a beautiful note book but not much fun in Chinese

Comment: Error `0x8007003` means the program cannot find the path specified. Assuming the path is correct, try putting the `.cab` file elsewhere, and try again with the new path.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. I tried by putting it on a my USB stick (E drive, no other drives available to my knowledge). It gave the same error though both when the file was lp and lp.mlc. Any other suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: @user321984 - You can't.  Your license does not give you that right.  Upgrade to Windows 8.1 Profession for that right.

Answer (score 0):

As the name indicates, Single language means you only have a single UI language and you are not allows to change it.

You need a English ISO/DVD and reinstall the Windows to change the language.

You can find the official Windows 8.1 ISOs [here](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/47732-The-Windows-8-1-(-amp-related)-Repository#a7vii). You want the one marked as “Single Language”.

Comment: Dear magicandre1981 and Ramhoud, thank you both for your comments. If it get it well I will need to do a clean install anyhow. Thank you for the posts.

Comment: yes, you need to reinstall Windows with an English Single Language DVD

Comment: I tried the clean install with a genuine windows key (8.1) bought from the US. The only language option was Chinese and I presumed once I installed with this key I could change it afterwards from the language options in the setting. However when I got there I could not do so, nor did I see an English language option when I tried a new install again. I am puzzled how to get to English now. Any assistance of directions most appreciated!

Comment: have you used an English ISO? The key is language independent. It makes no difference where you bought the key, the language of the ISO is important.

Comment: Yes, I have an finally managed to change everything except my log-off button and the place where I type my password when starting-up. I figured that with another clean install it would be oke but when I checked I noticed I also once again could only select Chinese. Is there anyway to make these last adjustments to EN as well?

Comment: I have no idea what you have changed now to make some parts English.

Comment: Solved it by changing all users accounts to En/UK. Now also the start-up menu is in English.