# Changing the language in Windows 8.1 single language

Tags: display, windows-8.1, language

I followed the instructions in this  question [How to install a new "display language" onto Windows 8.1 Single Language?](https://superuser.com/questions/666978/how-to-install-a-new-display-language-onto-windows-8-1-single-language) but now windows won't start properly, the screen is on but it's just black and I can see the cursor if I move it but I can't do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

This edition is not licensed to have multiple languages installed, because the licence policy entry `Kernel-MUI-Number-Allowed` only allows 1 language:

```
<sl:policyInt attributes="reboot-required, override-only" name="Kernel-MUI-Number-Allowed">1</sl:policyInt>
```

for the SingleLanguage SKU:

```
<sl:policyStr name="Kernel-EditionName">CoreSingleLanguage</sl:policyStr><sl:policyStr name="Kernel-CompositionEdition">CoreSingleLanguage</sl:policyStr>
```

Buy the normal Core edition which allows the install of new languages.

Comment: Yeah I know it won't support multiple languages, that's why I tried what the question said. I actually fixed my problem by going into recovery and restoring Windows. Then Everything worked great in the new language I installed.

Comment: all those hacks make your Windows "non genuine". So ignore them and buy the regular Core edition.

Comment: It's not actually a hack, you just force install a new language. Considering they don't give you the ability to choose a display language and the product key is still activated I'd say it's a pretty neat trick to save a hundred bucks. It's not like you need to change the language after you get the one you already want.

Comment: @McDonald's I've added some detail, but the trolls won't understand this complex topic.

Comment: @McDonald's - There wasn't anything wrong with this particular answer originally.  Just because it's in the review queue doesn't mean there is something wrong with it.

Comment: No worries Andre!! I thought you used to have a wall of trolls or something like that too, lol!