# How to change display language with cmd

Tags: cmd.exe, language, reset

So... I have a big big problem guys.
I bought windows 8.1 tablet PC in china.
And It was chinese single language edition.
So i tried to change my tablet PC's display language chinese to English.
I followed
[How to install a new "display language" onto Windows 8.1 Single Language?](https://superuser.com/questions/666978/how-to-install-a-new-display-language-onto-windows-8-1-single-language)
And I rebooted my pc after uninstalled chinese language.
After this my Pc didn't work. It just opened cmd by itself.
I only can open cmd.exe
Can I change language by using cmd?
If i can how to change?

Comment: Take a look: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-a-Display-Language-on-Windows-7-Without-Vistalizator

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this link:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721887(WS.10).aspx

You will need to create a custom XML file containing your locale/language settings and invoke this line from a batch file or the CLI:

control intl.cpl,, /f:“filename.xml”

Answer (score 0):

You can bring up the language menu by typing "Intl.cpl" in the CMD window.
You should be able to change it from there.