# Removed language package and Windows 8.1 doesn't start again

Tags: windows-8, display, language, package-management, packages

I was trying to change my windows display language. I used the instructions in this link 
[How to install a new "display language" onto Windows 8.1 Single Language?](https://superuser.com/questions/666978/how-to-install-a-new-display-language-onto-windows-8-1-single-language)
Now my computer doesn't start again. I just get a dark screen. How can I solve this? Please help

Comment: Which **exact** instructions did you use? There are multiple answers to the linked question.

Comment: We will need more information if you want assistance.  There is a reason the official response to how to do this is to upgrade Windows 8.1 Professional and not using the hack solutions posted by those users.

Answer (score 0):

I also followed [@egaistek's answer](https://superuser.com/a/717293/117691), and also ended up with an unbootable machine.

To recover, I [created installation media](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) (USB in my case), booted from it, chose advanced => system restore. I found that `DISM` creates a restore point before it makes changes, so I restored to that point, and then the machine booted back to its single-language pt-BR self.